# How to modify a project to use a local file instead of Firebase for storage?

Tags: javascript, json, electron

I'm interested in modifying this project:
[Bookmarking App with Electron](https://github.com/coligo-io/bookmarking-app-electron-vuejs-firebase)

This is my first interaction with Electron, and this project uses Firebase, but I'm not familiar with it, and it would be really nice if I could use a local `.json` file for storage. The code that handles the database is this:

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events'
import Firebase from 'firebase'

// ENTER YOUR FIREBASE URL BELOW
const db = Firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: 'YOUR_FIREBASE_APP_SECRET',
    databaseURL: 'https://YOUR_FIREBASE_APP.firebaseio.com/',
});
const categoriesRef = db.database().ref().child('categories')
const bookmarksRef = db.database().ref().child('bookmarks')
const store = new EventEmitter()

let categories = {}
let bookmarks = {}

db.database().ref().on('value', (snapshot) => {
    var bookmarkData = snapshot.val()
    if (bookmarkData) {
        categories = bookmarkData.categories
        bookmarks = bookmarkData.bookmarks
        store.emit('data-updated', categories, bookmarks)
    }
})

store.addCategory = (category) => {
    categoriesRef.update(category)
}

store.deleteCategory = (catName) => {
    // first check if an 'Uncategorized' category exists, if not, create it
    if (!('Uncategorized' in categories)) {
        categoriesRef.update({ 'Uncategorized': 'white' })
    }

    for (var key in bookmarks) {
        if (bookmarks[key].category === catName) {
            bookmarksRef.child(key).update({ category: 'Uncategorized' })
        }
    }
    categoriesRef.child(catName).remove()
}

store.addBookmark = (bookmark) => {
    bookmarksRef.push(bookmark)
}

store.deleteBookmark = (bookmarkId) => {
    bookmarksRef.child(bookmarkId).remove()
}

export default store
```

My goal is to use a local `.json` file for the storage, but I really am not familiar with JavaScript for system programming, so this probably is simple.

Comment: There exists a json filesystem store package on npm you can use but don't expect it to be performant as firebase.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-fs-store

Comment: Performance won't be an issue, because it will be a single user app, for now.

Comment: Alright. With some few updates to the code, you can make this work. Have fun!